# How can I add a new line to a large file every n characters in terminal (one liner sed)?

Tags: bash, shell, text, sed, replace

What am I missing here?

**file.txt:**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**in Terminal:**

```
> sed "s/.\{3\}/&\n/g" < file.txt > new-file.txt
```

**result: new-file.txt**

```
ABCnDEFnGHInJKLnMNOnPQRnSTUnVWXnYZ
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ABC
DEF
...
VWX
YZ
```

Comment: Your code actually gives your expected result when I run it with GNU sed on my linux box. Hmmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.../&\n/g' file.txt
```

#### Or use `grep`:

```
$ grep -oE '.{1,3}' file.txt
```

#### result:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo abcdefghi | dd cbs=3 conv=unblock 2>/dev/null 
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: \o/ this is the only answer that is also able to split continuous input (eg `cat /dev/random | base64 | dd cbs=10 conv=unblock`)

Answer (score 2):

Just with bash:

```
while read -n 3 chars; do printf "%s\n" "$chars"; done < file.txt > new-file.txt
```

Comment: this almost works. if there are less then X number of characters left over those get dropped off the end.

Comment: I don't understand your comment: `echo 1234568790 | while read -n3 a; do echo "$a"; done` -- does that not give the expected output? I don't see any dropped chars.

Answer (score 2):

An option, although maybe not quite correct depending on your input file is the gnu coreutil [`fold`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(Unix)). This will wrap lines so that no line is more than `w` characters long, e.g.:

```sh
$ <<< 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' fold -w3
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to explicitly hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while typing the `sed` command:

```
$ sed 's/.\{3\}/&\ 
/g' < file.txt > new-file.txt
$ cat new-file.txt
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 0):

The following ended up working for me:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.{3})/\1\n/sg' < file.txt > new-file.txt
```

Still not sure why the original didn't work.

Thanks for your help.